# How to synchronize sliders' values?

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider

I use jquery mobile sliders:

```html
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="0" min="0" max="255"  />
  </div><br><br>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <select name="switcher1" id="switcher1" data-role="slider">
      <option value="0">Off</option>
      <option value="255">On</option>
    </select> 
  </div>
```

It should work in the following way:

1. if switcher1 is touched, then slider1 value should be set either to 0 or to 255;
2. if slider1 value is changed, then (a) if it is = 0, then switcher1 should be set to 0, (b) else switcher1 value should be set to 255.

I've tried to do so with `change` event (the same is used for `switcher1` `change()`):

```js
var slider1_val = "0";
$('#slider1').change(function () {
    sVal = $(this).val();
    if (slider1_val !== sVal) {
        $("#slider1").val(sVal).slider("refresh");
        if (sVal == 0) {
            $("#switcher1").val(0).slider("refresh");
        } else {
            $("#switcher1").val(255).slider("refresh");
        }
        slider1_val = sVal;
    }
});
```

But looks like each call of `refresh` calls `change` event, so I am getting infinite loop.

Comment: Wouldn't it still work if you got rid of the `$("#slider1").val(sVal).slider("refresh"); `. It looks like you're setting the value to whatever it was already set to, which is unnecessary and is causing the change event to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should work in the following way:
>
> 1. if switcher1 is touched, then slider1 value should be set either to 0 or to 255;
> 2. if slider1 value is changed, then (a) if it is = 0, then switcher1 should be set to 0, (b) else switcher1 value should be set to 255.
>
> I've tried to do so with change event (the same is used for switcher1 change()):

The fact that you have two very different criteria for changing each control should tip you off that the change event handlers should be different as well. Using the same handlers leads to the infinite loop you are experiencing. The code below accounts for the strict change criteria you've provided. Note that the slider1 change handler changes switcher1 *only* if it needs to be changed (based on your criteria), not *every* time it is called. Also, note that in the slider1 change handler, `switcher1_val` is set *before* calling refresh, so that in case .`slider('refresh')` *does* call the change handler, the change handler will not do anything, because `switcher1_val` is already updated.

```
var linkSliders = function(sliderId, switcherId){
    var slider = $('#'+sliderId),
        switcher = $('#'+switcherId);
    var min = Math.min(switcher[0].options[0].value, switcher[0].options[1].value),
        max = Math.max(switcher[0].options[0].value, switcher[0].options[1].value);
    var sliderVal = switcherVal = min;

    // set the slider min/max to be the same as the switcher's, just in case they're different
    slider.attr('max', max).attr('min', min).slider('refresh');  
    slider.change(function(){
        var sVal = $(this).val();
        if(sliderVal != sVal){
            if( sVal == min && switcherVal!=min){
                switcherVal=min;
                switcher.val(min).slider('refresh');
            }else if(sVal>min && switcherVal!=max){
                switcherVal=max;
                switcher.val(max).slider('refresh');
            }
            sliderVal = sVal;
        }
    });  

    switcher.change(function(){
        var sVal = $(this).val();
        if(switcherVal != sVal){
            slider.val(sVal).slider('refresh');
            switcherVal = sVal;
        }
    });
};

linkSliders('slider1','switcher1');
```

[See the live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/ahreL/)

Hope this helps.

---

Update: As requested, the example has been modified to make it more general.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. Could you please help me to make that more universal? Let's say if I have 4 pages and each contain switcher and slider (i.e. page1 contains switcher1 and slider1, page2 contains switcher2 and slider2 and so on). Also I am wondering if it is possible to use `$('.ui-slider-handle').live('touchend'` instead of `$('#switcher1').change(`. Will not it be more effective?

Comment: I've updated the example to make it more general: http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/ahreL/.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly, but not in my case ;) - I have one slider and one switcher on page 1, one slider and one switcher on page 2 and so on and I am getting error - `uncaught exception: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'`, when I call  `linkSliders('slider2','switcher2')`.

Comment: We need to see your page structure and where your code is and when your code is called in order to properly address this error. Can you post your full html/js, either in a fiddle or as an update to your original Q.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work because we don't keep current value of each switcher and each slider...

Comment: I've found solution - `$( '#device1' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event, ui){ linkSliders('slider1','switcher1'); });     $( '#device2' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event, ui){ linkSliders('slider2','switcher2'); }); `